# Jquery Slider Wrapper Not Working

Tags: jquery, text, slider, wrapper

So I'm fairly new to Jquery, but the follow code seems as though it should work. I had this working with slightly different code to wrap from slide 1 to slide 4 if the 'previous' button was clicked, and to go to slide 1 from slide 4 if 'next' was clicked. In the processing of recoding the jquery to be more dynamic, it basically doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<html><title>JQuery Test</title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#mydiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid navy;
  margin: 25px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18;
  background-color: #0899bd;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
 }
#mydiv p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 9;
     color: rgb(192,192,192);
     padding: 10px;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="mydiv">
 <ul>
 <li style="list-style-type: none; display: none;"; >This is my first Slide.</li>

 <li style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">This is my 2nd Slide.</li>
 
 <li style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">This is my 3rd Slide.</li>
 
 <li style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">This is my 4th Slide</li>
</ul>
</div>
<button style="margin-left: 240px;" id="prevSlide">Previous</button>
<button id="nextSlide">Next</button>

<script>
var currSlide = $('li').first();
currSlide.fadeIn(5000);

$('#prevSlide').click(function() {
 if (currSlide == $('li').first()) {
  currSlide.toggle();
  currSlide = $('li').last();
  currSlide.toggle(180);
 } else {
  currSlide.toggle();
  currSlide = currSlide.prev();
  currSlide.toggle(18);
 }
});

$('nextSlide').click(function() {
 if ($currSlide == $('li').last()) {
  $currSlide.toggle();
  $currSlide = $('li').first();
  $currSlide.toggle(180);
 } else {
  $currSlide.toggle();
  $currSlide = $currSlide.next();
  $currSlide.toggle(180);
 }
});
</script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corrected version of your code:

You don't have to add a $ before your variable name.

To check if you are on the latest item, you can just check the .next().length property. If it is true, it has a next item.

P.S: I did not improve your code too much in order to allow you understand where you have made your mistakes.

```
<html><title>JQuery Test</title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#mydiv {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 3px solid navy;
        margin: 25px;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 18;
        background-color: #0899bd;
        padding-right: 30px;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
#mydiv p {
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 9;
        color: rgb(192,192,192);
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="mydiv">
    <ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none; display: none;"; >This is my first Slide.</li>

    <li style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">This is my 2nd Slide.</li>

    <li style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">This is my 3rd Slide.</li>

    <li style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">This is my 4th Slide</li>
</ul>
</div>
<button style="margin-left: 240px;" id="prevSlide">Previous</button>
<button id="nextSlide">Next</button>

<script>
var currSlide = $('li').first();
currSlide.fadeIn(5000);

$('#prevSlide').click(function() {
    if (currSlide.prev().length) {
        currSlide.toggle();
        currSlide = currSlide.prev();
        currSlide.toggle(180);

    } else {
        currSlide.toggle();
        currSlide = $('li').last();
        currSlide.fadeIn(180);
    }
});

$('#nextSlide').click(function() {
    if (currSlide.next().length) {
        currSlide.toggle();
        currSlide = currSlide.next();
        currSlide.toggle(180);
    } else {
        currSlide.toggle();
        currSlide = $('li').first();
        currSlide.fadeIn(180);

    }
});
</script>


</body></html>
```